# Why does water heater closet door jump open?

Tags: water-heater

I have a gas water heater inside a small closet with a door.  Sometimes that door jumps open a few inches, as if there is a blast of air pressure inside.  This door even has a small vent in it.  What causes this, and is it something I should be worried about?

Comment: Does the door open into or out of the closet?

Comment: Sounds more likely the door just isn't latching properly...

Answer (score 1):

With a gas water heater there could be whoosh of air pressure change just as the heater comes on to heat the water. That could in turn create a suction and then a release as the air pressure re-equalizes that makes the door come open.

Mitigation of the problem may be as simple as putting a catch on the door that has a stronger detent. Or if possible install a conventional door knob and latch . . . although that will be harder if the door is only thin 3/4" or 7/8" door.

Another possibility is that the exhaust vent for the heater is not shrouded correctly above your roof line and is allowing a down draft into the closet that pushes the door open.